# bash : sed : regex in variable

Tags: bash, sed

I'm getting totally crazy with the following script.

The following command works as expected :

```
echo a | sed 's/a/b/'
```

Output :

```
b
```

But this script doesn't :

```
test="'s/a/b/'"
echo a | sed $test
```

Output :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command : `''
```

I should really be stupid, but I don't see what I am missing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your double wrapping your string. `test="'s/a/b'"`. Sed then gets `'s/a/b/'` as literal string. You only want sed to receive `s/a/b/`.
You only need to wrap the string in **one set of quotes**, otherwise the inner set of quotes will be interpreted as part of the argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
test="'s/a/b/'"
echo a | sed $test
```

is equivalent to:

```
test="'s/a/b/'"
echo a | sed "'s/a/b/'"
```

Obviously `sed` doesn't understand the command with both `"` and `'`, It interprets `'` as a command. You can use either one of them:

```
test='s/a/b/'
```

Or

```
test='s/a/b/'
```

Answer (score 1):

you may want this:

```
kent$  test="s/a/b/"         

kent$  echo a | sed ${test}
b
```

or

```
kent$  echo a | sed $test  
b
```

or

```
test=s/a/b/
```